# How do I ask a pupil in what specific Grade he is ? (for example 7A, 7B etc)

Tags: questions

in the 80s and 90s when I was in school in Romania, each romanian school had a class (in other words all pupils in for example Grade 7 of that school) divided into several units, each unit being approx. 28 pupils who attended all classes in the same classroom together. Each unit was called 7A, 7B etc. So for example I was "in 7B".

I know that to ask a pupil what Grade he is, you simply ask him "What Grade are you ?", to which the answer would be for example "I'm Grade 7".

My question is, please, how do I ask a pupil in what specific Grade he is ? (for example 7A, 7B etc)

Thank you so much,

Adrian.

Comment: "What class are you in?"?

Comment: In British English you might use "form" instead of "class" (although it might vary regionally or between state and fee-paying schools, etc), but it's not clear what variety of English you're using or indeed why you are asking Romanians something in English.

Comment: Since you call them units then i’d ask, “Which unit are you in?”  I think in general that it varies by school what they call their subdivisions within a grade.  Some divide into homerooms, some Into cohorts, some into legions, some into sections, etc.  and the question to ask depends on the name they use for their subdivision.

Comment: You may just use two questions.  "What grade are you in?" ... "I'm in grade 7." ... "A or B?"

Comment: You are on the wrong site. Please read the label. Try English Language Learners.

Comment: For Stuart:  globalisation :)))))  No, on a more serious note, I wanted to know how one asks it, not necessarily in Romania, but all around the globe in English.

Comment: For David:  ok I have read now what "English Language and Usage" is for. Thanks for the notification  :)     I'll ask the questions on "English Language Learners" from now on.

Answer (score -2):

Ask "What **year** are you in?". Year 1 is mostly 5-year-olds, though most will turn 6 while in Year 1. Year 7 is 11 (or 12)-year-olds. And so on.

Comment: Thanks, Rosie, but it didn't answer my question. It's ok, the contributors here above did. Thank you all.